# ShapeCache not being set up-- plist file not being loaded?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, plist, box2d

So I asked a slightly similar question to this one but did not get it answered so I figured I would look into it more myself and narrow my problem down to make it more simple.

In my Box2D game I am using Physics Editor to deal with my collision detection. In my main class (GameLayer), I have a method which sets up the ShapeCache and I put it in the init:

```
- (void)setupShapeCache
{
    [[ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addShapesWithFile:@"shapes.plist"];
}
```

"shapes.plist" is in my targets (under copy bundle resources) and it's in my resources folder of my project with the same name as it is used throughout my xcode project.

As I run my game I keep getting an assertion failed error in my ShapeCache class. I have figured out that this is because the "shapes.plist" file never loads.

The exact error looks like:

```
Assertion failed: (so), function -[ShapeCache addFixturesToBody:forShapeName:userdataCallBack:],
 file /Users/***/Desktop/***/***/ShapeCache.mm, line 92.
```

My ShapeCache class is adapted from the Space Game Starter Kit but I do not believe that that makes a difference (SpaceGame ShapeCache vs PhysicsEditor ShapeCache)

Does anyone have any idea as to **why** my physics editor plist (shapes.plist) never loads?

If any more information would help please tell me!

Thank you so much!

:)

Comment: Have you double checked the capitalization? Are you sure it's not 'Shapes.plist' vs 'shapes.plist' ?

Comment: and the shapes.plist is in the xcode project and included in the target? (check: copy bundle resouces build phase)